# Rotation and opacity causes text rendering issues in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I've run into an odd text rendering issue with Firefox. I have a div that is rotated, and another div inside it has it's opacity rapidly changed between 1 and 0.5. This causes any text inside the div to render differently each time the opacity changes - some numbers will shift up or down by a pixel, parts of the text will be thicker or narrower.

As an example, this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="glowyWrapper">
    <div class="glowy transparent"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="someText">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</p>
</div>
```

With these styles:

```
.outer {
  transform: rotate(1deg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.glowyWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

.glowy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.someText {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Adding a bit of javascript to repeatedly add and remove the "transparent" class will cause the rendering issue.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/projectx593/n01m1jop/10/

I have found a few workarounds, like decreasing the rate the opacity changes, or having it alternate between 0.95 but I'd rather not have to adjust the speed of it if possible, or have the flashing div be always transparent to some degree. Is there a better solution to this?

I found the issue in Firefox version 46.0

Comment: The bug doesn't occur if you set the interval delay to 500ms or bigger.

Comment: as previous comment a short transition avoid the bug, a little shadow will also smoothen edges https://jsfiddle.net/n01m1jop/11/ or /12/ +filter(blur instead box-shadow or even only filter https://jsfiddle.net/n01m1jop/14/

Comment: Can you list the Firefox version? Because this wasn't happening back in 33.

Comment: Done. I noticed my Firefox was out of date, the issue still occurred after updating to 46.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `transform` is already there and `-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;` useless  you may use a filter to force FF render calculation, so you cure also the stair effect on edges.

```
  filter: blur(0.1px);/* note that even 0 as value does it */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n01m1jop/14/